# Smarty current language

Tags: php, css, smarty, multilingual

I have two language on my web, and want to set one of them active when user choose any language from them. I assign to Smarty variable with value of current language ({$current_language}), set in my CSS file active flag for .en-active, and .ru-active, and wrote that code

```
    {if $current_lang eq 'ru'}
        {assign var='ru_active' value="ru-active"}
    {elseif $current_lang eq 'en'}
        {assign var='en_active' value="en-active"}
    {/if}
    <a href="index.php?lang=ru" class="ru {$ru_active}"></a>
    <a href="index.php?lang=en" class="en {$en_active}"></a>
```

All work fine, but mby there is more clean way to do that ?

I tried else do something like this, without if checking:

```
    {assign var='ru_active' value={$current_lang|cat:"-active"}
    {assign var='en_active' value={$current_lang|cat:"-active"}

    <a href="index.php?lang=ru" class="ru {$ru_active}"></a>
    <a href="index.php?lang=en" class="en {$en_active}"></a>
```

But i dont think that it's a good idea. So maybe somebody can suggest really cool and clean method to do that.

P.S I don't have my language list in array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make something like that:

```
<style>
.{$current_lang}{
   color: green;
}
</style>
```

"color: green;" you can replace with inside from your active class

Don't worry about using `<style> </style>` in your .tpl code, it's ok.

Comment: Second dont work normally, it's my mind way how it mby can be realised :) But thanks.

Comment: Maybe make somthing like that:

<style>
.{$current_lang}{
color: green;
}
</style>